# VueJs/Vuetify Barcode Reader How to emit scanned value to currently focused input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to emit the scanned value to the currently focused input field. The Scanner is placed inside of a component, that is placed in the `App.vue` next to the `router-view` so i can always access the scanner in any navigation route.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <FABScanner :visible="true" /> <!-- Component -->
  </v-container>
</template>
```

For the scanner im using `StreamBarcodeReader` from `vue-barcode-reader`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-fab-transition>
      <v-btn v-show="visible" class="mb-16" color="warning" fab bottom right absolute @click="showCamera = !showCamera">
        <v-icon>fa-solid fa-barcode</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-fab-transition>
    <StreamBarcodeReader v-if="showCamera" @decode="(a, b, c) => onDecode(a, b, c)" @loaded="() => onLoaded()" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { StreamBarcodeReader } from "vue-barcode-reader";
export default {
  components: { StreamBarcodeReader },
  props: {
    visible: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    value: { type: String, required: false, default: undefined }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showCamera: false,
      timeout: undefined,
      text: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDecode(a, b, c) {
      this.text = a;
      if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.text === a) {
          this.text = "";
        }
      }, 5000);
      this.$root.$emit('showSnackBar', { color: 'success', text: `${this.text}` });
      this.showCamera = false
    },
    onLoaded() {
      console.log('Camera loaded.')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Due to the fact i have various inputs, i cant use `$refs` to change the value of an input. So i tried changing the value in the `DOM` like this

```
onDecode(a, b, c) {
      this.text = a;
      if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.text === a) {
          this.text = "";
        }
      }, 5000);
      this.$root.$emit('showSnackBar', { color: 'success', text: `${this.text}` });
      this.showCamera = false

      const focused = document.activeElement
      if (!focused) return
      focused.value = this.text
    },
```

This is changing the value, but it is not firing the `@update` inside of the input.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to achieve this.

By using `vuex` store i can set and get the value. With a `watch` function on the store state i now can handle the change of the value and therefor update the input value with `$refs`.